# Unable to use click event in Phonegap Build after ver 2.5

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, phonegap-build

I am building an app with PhoneGap build 2.9.0 for Android. However my click function seems to not work (I tap the button but nothing happens), while it used to work in PhoneGap Build ver 2.5.0. How can I overcome this issue?

My simple code is below:

```
$(document).on('click', '#submitButton', function ()
```

Is this an issue with JQM, jquery or phonegap itself and how can I overcome it?

Comment: Does it work in the browser? Any errors? Full code of the function?

Comment: works in browser with no errors. In the app itself this issue happens

Comment: Hm, I have ported a rather large app from 2.1 over 2.5 to 2.9 without any issues, so I don't think it's a PhoneGap issue. You can try to build it locally or use a debugger like [weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/) to debug it.

Comment: If I use build ver 2.5 it works so am not sure what is the issue @jgillich

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JQM with ajax loading, try using the live event.

**Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submitButton').live('click', function() {
    //CODE HERE
  });
});
```

Comment: Ahh.. Thanks for that, I wasn't aware.